# Accidentally commit pushed to an unknown place

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repo that is "origin"
I also push it to Heroku, that repo is "uat"

I was trying to push to uat like

```
git push uat [branch name]:master
```

but I accidentally did this

```
git push origin uat/master
```

and the result is

```
To git@github.com:[origin name].git
 * [new branch]      uat/master -> uat/master
```

But when I go to GitHub, I cannot find that branch.
How can I delete this from GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to delete the remote branch using

```
git push origin :uat/master
```

This should delete the remote branch that you accidentally created.